# How should I set driver core in Spark Cluster Mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen a lot of articles about executor memories/cores/instances, but I still don't get what should I set for driver core. What's the benefit of increasing it? What's the appropriate value for it?(My yarn is total 12 vcores + 36GB Memory)

Comment: The Spark driver is a kind of coordinator that distributes the load to the executors. As far as you don’t use some Spark actions that brings back a lot of data from executor to the driver, 1 vcore + 1GB memory is usually sufficient.

Comment: then if I use actions like collect / saving parquet / approxquantile .. should I increase vcore? I read memory should be at least as large as the size of the memory.

Comment: You don't need to increase vcore, just memory. If you save to a distributed file system like HDFS, this is done by the executors

Comment: What about cloud? I am using cloud storage(google cloud) and it looked like driver is doing it. Thanks for the answers by the way. :)

Comment: does this mean that there is no point in increasing driver cores when not using any `collect`-like apis? what about jobs with a lot of tasks, say 100K tasks in a stage? will more cores help the driver deal with all the events coming from individual tasks?